# Bitcoin Core crashes on XP twice

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

I recently backed up my blockchain to an external drive and restored my computer from Windows 10 to XP. Afterwards, I copied the blockchain back to my hard drive and downloaded a portable copy of Bitcoin Core and ran it. It said it had many hours to sync, and I left it overnight. When I came back, it had crashed with XP's message about it needing to close. I opened it again and it said that some part of the blockchain files were corrupt and started syncing from 2009. I restored my backup again and it only had 34 hours to catch up on.

Today I got up and the same error was displayed. But this time when I reopened it, it only has to catch up on 2 hours. If it works then that's great, but does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: How much RAM does your XP machine have? What version of Bitcoin Core are you running? [\*SCNR\*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QMH9k.png)

Comment: 2 GB RAM. Version 0.11.2. I've disabled the computer's power options. It's lasting longer than usual this time, so I think it had to do with power options. I'll leave it running tonight and see if that helps.

Comment: This morning I saw it had crashed again. Upon restarting it said the block database was corrupted, so something keeps happening after a certain amount of time.

Comment: I started up the portable copy of the node and it is now syncing again from 10 hours. Same copy of blockchain that was reported bad by the installed copy but this time no messages about corrupt block database. I can't imagine the portable and installed Bitcoin Core, both 0.11.2, disagreeing. And, after waiting a few hours, they are both OK with my blockchain, no messages at all.

Comment: I can't make 0.12.x run on XP, and I still can't understand why 0.11.2 won't work. Over on GitHub some users report being able to use 0.11.2 on XP, but mine still crashes. My XP machine keeps 0.10.3 running longer than 0.11.2, but even that keeps crashing after a while, half the time saying "Expression: hashPrevBlock == view.GetBestBlock()" and other times the generic "Bitcoin has to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience". If it helps, the former error comes from main.cpp, line 1660.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by going back to Windows 10. Bitcoin Core no longer crashes, and my node has in fact been running nonstop for days.